# A question about rational.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

Is that true : Every positive rational number $q$ can be written as $q = \sum_{i=0}^{k}1/n_i$ , where $n_i,k$ are positive intergers and $n_i\not=n_j$ if $i\not=j$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Express the fraction $\dfrac{a}{b}$ as a sum of $a$ copies of $\dfrac{1}{b}$.  (For technical reasons, if $b=1$, use $2a$ copies of $\dfrac{1}{2}$.) Major flaw: the denominators are not all different.

Using repeatedly the identity 
$$\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k(k+1)},\tag{$1$}$$
 we can express any $\dfrac{1}{n}$ as a sum of distinct unit fractions with all denominators as large as we wish.

So leave the first $\dfrac{1}{b}$ alone. Express the second one as $\dfrac{1}{b+1}+\dfrac{1}{b(b+1}$. For the third $\dfrac{1}{b}$, use Identity $(1)$ repeatedly to express $\dfrac{1}{b}$ as a sum of distinct unit fractions with denominators all greater than $b(b+1)$. Continue.

The algorithm we have described is quite inefficient. There are much better algorithms available, going back to Fibonacci's greedy algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> An Egyptian fraction is the sum of distinct unit fractions, such as .
>   That is, each fraction in the expression has a numerator equal to 1
>   and a denominator that is a positive integer, and all the denominators
>   differ from each other. The value of an expression of this type is a
>   positive rational number a/b; for instance the Egyptian fraction above
>   sums to 43/48. Every positive rational number can be represented by an
>   Egyptian fraction. Sums of this type, and similar sums also including
>   2/3 and 3/4 as summands, were used as a serious notation for rational
>   numbers by the ancient Egyptians, and continued to be used by other
>   civilizations into medieval times. In modern mathematical notation,
>   Egyptian fractions have been superseded by vulgar fractions and
>   decimal notation. However, Egyptian fractions continue to be an object
>   of study in modern number theory and recreational mathematics, as well
>   as in modern historical studies of ancient mathematics.

From Wikipedia.
Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction